# Fallout Shelter Android files missing

Tags: fallout-shelter, android

I want to copy save over to my new phone, but the whole com.bethsoft.falloutshelter folder is missing. I can play the game but I can't see any of the Fallout Shelter files in my phone.

I put the settings on Show hidden system files, but nothing changed regarding these files.

(Sort of fixed, used an USB cable to my phone and then i could see em)

Comment: Likely related to system permissions. Which version of Android are you using?

Comment: Does it actually need to be copied by yourself? Like, doesn't it have Play Games cloud save or something? *Edit:* It does seems to have [cloud save system](https://help.bethesda.net/#en/answer/31236).